# Solution of nonlinear ODE: $x= yy'-(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve 
$x= yy'-(y')^2.$
 Can somebody please hint at some substitution or refer any text related to these type of ode.

Comment: it is a D' Alembert equation, Google for it

Answer (score 4):

Start by rearranging your equation: Add both sides by $(y')^2$, then divide both sides by $y'$. We obtain:
$$y=\frac{x}{y'}+y'\tag{1}$$
Notice that $(1)$ is a [d'Alembert equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html). This is because it is in the form:
$$y=x\cdot f(y')+g(y')$$
Where $f$ and $g$ are functions of $y'$. These are typically solved by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:
$$y'=\frac{y'-xy''}{(y')^2}+y''$$
This can be rearranged to give:
$$y''=\frac{y'\left((y')^2-1\right)}{(y')^2-x}$$
Now substitute $v=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. We know that $\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{dx(v)}{dv}}$. As a result, we obtain a first-order linear ODE with $v$ as the independent variable and $x$ as the dependent variable.
$$\frac{1}{\frac{dx(v)}{dv}}=\frac{v(v^2-1)}{v^2-x} \implies \frac{dx}{dv}+\frac{1}{v(v^2-1)}\cdot x=\frac{v}{v^2-1} \tag{2}$$
This can be solved using an integrating factor.

Comment: I  got the solution in terms of $ x (v)$.Now how to proceed. $x (v)=\frac {vlogc (v+\sqrt (v^2-1))}{\sqrt (v^2-1)}$

Comment: Using the quadratic formula on your original ODE:
$$y'=\frac{y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4x}}{2} \tag{3}$$
Substitute back $v=y'$ on your solution for $x(v)$, and substitute $(3)$ to obtain $x$ as a function of $y$.